# Linear expression for intersection length of two lines in 1D

Tags: math, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, line-intersection

Given the first line from `a` to `b` where `a < b` and the second line from `x` to `y` where `x < y`, how do you calculate the intersection length of those two?

Example:

```
a =0, b=5, x=3, y=7

012345
|----|
   |---|
   34567
```

the result would be `2` since they are intersection from `3` to `5`.

Is there an expression with these 4 variables to extract the result? There is no guarantee that there is an intersection nor is it guaranteed that `x > a`

I have looked at timespan intersection examples but they all have an `if` expression in them which is not possible in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

Logic is quite simple:

```
if (y<a) or (x>b):
       return  no intersection

intersection.left = max(a, x)
intersectioni.right = min(b, y)
```

Comment: But this isnt an linear expression.

Comment: What do you mean by "linear expression"?

Comment: a linear equation with these variables, something like 

`    is <= b`
`    is <= y`
`    ie >=a`
`    ie >=x`
`    i = ie - is`
`    maximise(i)`

so i can use it in an ilp formulation

Comment: Problem statement does not assume maximisation and other kinds of optimization, it has single exact solution.